# Standard and Polar Coordinate Conversions on $S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

I'm having a little trouble formalizing the idea of using "ambient standard coordinates" on level sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example, we typically write $S^1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$, which can be seen as the (regular) level set $f^{-1}(1)$ associated to the smooth function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. From what I understand, we can view these $x,y$ as the coordinate functions that come from the standard coordinate chart $\varphi$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Suppose I wanted to define a vector field $X$ on a (connected) open subset of $S^1$. In this case, I'd be working with the usual angle coordinate $\theta:U\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and so this vector field can be written on $U$ as $X_p=h(p)\frac{d}{d\theta}$. Essentially, what formally/rigorously allows us to also express this vector field as (say) $$X_p=y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$
using the standard coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^2$? The angle coordinate $\theta:U\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^1$ has one coordinate function, so I'm not sure how we can apply the change of coordinates formula in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (see pg. 63), since $\varphi=(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ has two coordinate functions. I suppose I'm *intuitively* comfortable working with these standard coordinates (say, in the sense of multivariable calculus), but I think it would be especially helpful for my understanding how this intuition is formalized.

A small footnote: when I expressed $X_p$ in terms of standard coordinates, I was using the fact that $T_pS^1$ consists of vectors which are orthogonal to the point $p=(x,y)$. I'm able to see why I can do this by examining $\ker df_p$.

Comment: The main idea is that for any point $p \in \mathbb{S}^1$ we can view $T_p \mathbb{S}^1$ as a subspace of $T_p \mathbb{R}^2$ (see the section "The Tangent Space to a Submanifold" in the book of Lee that you have cited) and of course since $\mathbb{S}^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ we can describe $p$ by its Cartesian coordinates as well. This is more of a "change of frame" then it is a "change of coordinates".

Comment: @jd27 thank you for the reference. I'm taking a look at Proposition 5.37, in which he shows that $T_pS^1=d\iota_p(T_pS^1)$ is spanned by $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_p$. Is this "change of frame" procedure just the identification of $\left.\frac{d}{d\theta}\right|_p$ with $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_p$ via $d\iota_p$? Also, while we can certainly describe $S^1$ using standard coordinates, technically $x,y$ do NOT form a coordinate chart for $S^1$, right? I'm interpreting them as convenient functions which encode points on $S^1$, yet do not form charts for $S^1$.

Comment: What is the definition of $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_p$ as an element of $T_pS^1$ here? Using the standard embedding of $S^1$ in $\Bbb R^2$ to consider $T_pS^1$ to be a subspace of $T_p\Bbb R^2, \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_p$ is only going be in that subspace when $p = (0, \pm 1)$. Is this proposition only applicable to those two points, or in claiming that $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_p$ spans $T_pS^1$, are you referring to the span of its projection into that subspace?

Comment: @PaulSinclair my apologies, I believe I conflated the slice coordinates being used in the proof of Proposition 5.37 with the standard coordinates used on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I think I'm just looking to understand how one should rigorously view this "change of frame" procedure. For example, I'll oftentimes see vector fields $X$ (on $S^1$, say) written with component functions in $\theta$ (at a point $p=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$), but with $\partial/\partial x$ and $\partial/\partial y$ as the chosen basis vectors for the coordinate representations of $X$, so that 2 coordinate systems are being used.

Comment: As I noted in my previous comment, $T_pS^1$ can be indentified with a subspace of $T_p\Bbb R^2$, so yes, it is possible to express the elements of $T_pS^1$ in terms of the basis $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_p, \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_p$ of $T_p\Bbb R^2$. Because $T_pS^1$ is one-dimensional, the span of any non-zero vector in it is the entire space, so it is not necessary for two vectors to be the same to both span the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to a local chart $(U,\theta)$ of $S^1$ and the global chart $\mathrm{id}=(x,y)$ of $\mathbb R^2$, the standard inclusion $i:S^1\to \mathbb R^2$ looks like
$$(x,y)(i(p))=(\cos(\theta(p)),\sin(\theta(p))).$$
This embedding induces a tangent map $Ti:TS^1\to T\mathbb R^2$, whose restriction to $TU\subseteq TS^1$ looks like
$$Ti\left(a\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\bigg|_{p}\right)=
a\left(
-\sin\theta(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg|_{i(p)}
+
\cos\theta(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial
y}\bigg|_{i(p)}
\right).$$
This map is injective at every point $p$ of $u$, and it is the identification of $T_pS^1$ with a subspace of $T_{i(p)}\mathbb R^2$ that jd27 was talking about.

Comment: This is super helpful; thank you!

Comment: I have one small question (my apologies, I completely missed this when I first accepted your answer): shouldn't the coordinate rep. of $Ti$ evaluated at $a\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}|_p$ have coordinates $-\sin\theta(p)$ and $\cos\theta(p)$ (rather than $\cos\theta(p)$ and $\sin\theta(p)$)? At least according to Lee, Eq. 3.10, it seems like $di_p\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right)=\frac{\partial \hat{i}^1}{\partial\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial \hat{i}^2}{\partial\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial y},$ where $\hat{i}^j$ is the $j$-th component of $(x,y)(i(p))$.

Comment: @LiminalSpace glad to be helpful. About your second comment, of course you are right. I edited the post already. Thanks for noticing.